# Name of expression?

Tags: c#, nullable, syntactic-sugar

I wrote some code a while ago, but I forgot the name of the syntactic sugar I used and can't find it anymore. I guess it had something with nullable in its name but I am not entirely sure.

That is what I did:

Instead  of writing something  like this

```
if(ReturningFunktion() != null)

{ 
   ReturningFunktion().AnotherFunktion();

}
```

you can write

```
ReturningFunktion()?.AnotherFunktion();
```

I can't remember what the ?. bit was called.

Comment: Hi and welcome, its called the null-conditional operator https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/member-access-operators#null-conditional-operators--and-

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a `Null-conditional operator`. You can always try to search such stuff or open Microsoft Documentation on C#: [Click me](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/member-access-operators#null-conditional-operators--and-)

Comment: Thanks I actually did search the Microsoft Documentation but putting Questionmarks in the search function doesn't work well.